# If I encrypt my system drive with VeraCrypt, can I be using the computer while this is happening?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, encryption, operating-systems

I'd like to encrypt the my system drive that my OS is on. This is my only computer, so I was wondering if encrypting it would prevent me from using it, presumably for days.

I've tried encrypting an external drive and I couldn't access it until it was done. But maybe I chose the wrong settings.

Is there a workaround? Like, maybe I can create a complete copy of my system drive and encrypt the original while using the other? I have no experience doing this. Just an idea.

Thank you for any help or advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot volume encryption is different than regular disk encryption. Veracrypt will first install its bootloader and reboot using it, asking you for password for the first time. The encryption will then begin on a live system. Performance will be degraded, but the computer will be usable. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_WkMELC790) shows the entire procedure. It's slightly dated, but still accurate even on Windows 10 systems.

But crucially, **it's absolutely necessary to make a full disk backup before the encryption**. If the process is interrupted it may lead to loss of data and VC-encrypted disks are difficult (and/or expensive) to recover data from. So your idea of making a copy beforehand is spot-on, even if not for the right reason.

LPChip's advice in the other answer is also good: if you have a Pro edition of Windows, I'd recommend using Bitlocker rather than Veracrypt. It's easier to use, works with TPM (safely removing the need for manual password entry), has better compatibility and lets you upgrade Windows [without jumping through extra hoops](https://github.com/th-wilde/veracrypt-w10-patcher).

Answer (score 0):

Your experiment told you all you need to know.

During the encryption process, the drive cannot be used. Given it is your OS drive, the entire encryption will happen outside of windows, so windows cannot be used either.

In essence you cannot use your computer while the encryption is on-going.

Keep in mind that an external drive is usually quite a bit slower than an internal drive, so it might be that the encryption process only takes an hour or so, not a whole day.

That said, You can use Windows' built-in bitlocker feature to encrypt your disk, and unlike veracrypt, this encryption feature happens in the background and windows can be used. It will however tie the decryption process to your user account, so anyone with the password of your user can also access your data. But if you take out the harddrive without the computer, your data is safe.

Comment: That's not correct. Boot volume encryption works differently and happens on a live system.

Comment: @gronostaj can you elaborate more? I have a feeling we're misunderstanding each other here. I don't think they are talking about boot encryption.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the boot drive: _"I'd like to encrypt the my system drive that my OS is on."_, _"maybe I can create a complete copy of my system drive and encrypt the original while using the other"_.

Comment: @gronostaj I read that as: the C partition, not the bootloader partition. That's where our confusion comes from.

Comment: By "bootloader partition" do you mean ESP? AFAIK no standard Windows installation uses a dedicated bootloader partition other than ESP, which cannot be encrypted because it must be readable for UEFI. And the OS partition encryption works as I described. There's a video of a step-by-step setup linked in my answer.